# EJB CDI injection in non-bean object?

Tags: java, javabeans, cdi, code-injection

I have

```
@Named("bean1")
@javax.enterprise.context.SessionScoped
public class Bean1 implements Serializable {
    // ...
}

@Named("bean2")
@javax.enterprise.context.SessionScoped
public class Bean2 implements Serializable {
    private SomeClass object = new SomeClass();
}
```

and

```
public class SomeClass {
    @Inject
    private Bean1 injBean;
}
```

My questions:

1) Bean2 is session scoped. Which scope does Bean2.object have? 
2) Why does the injection in someClass not work? Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> 1) Bean2 is session scoped. Which scope does Bean2.object have?

Well, `Bean2.object` is just an object inside a `Bean2` instance and thus doesn't have any CDI scope.

> 2) Why does the injection in someClass not work? Thanks.

There are at least two reasons:

- `someClass` (btw, check the naming conventions) is not a CDI managed bean
- The object referenced by `Bean2.object` is not created by CDI and thus CDI doesn't even know that instance exists.

To fix that, make `someClass` a managed bean and let CDI inject an instance into `Bean2.object`.

Comment: I thought that CDI would have a default scope for every class (@Dependant) and therefore every used class could be injected.
What is the real difference between having a CDI bean and a normal class which is referenced inside a session scoped bean? Isn't the session scoped been serialized and sent to the client as a stub? Thus I thought that the references to "normal objects" would get serialized which would mean that they are "session scoped", too. 

Thanks so far. The naming convention error was just a typo :-)!

Comment: @tenox I didn't dig into the inner workings of CDI that much, but AFAIK there aren't always stubs, in fact most objects would be plainly be injected. Even if a stub was used, it wouldn't be the object being serialized but rather a proxy generated from the object's signature. As for the scope: `Bean2.object` has a scope as every piece of code has, it's just not a CDI scope. If you really want to define the scope in terms of CDI it might be something like dependant scope, but it would only be similar, since CDI is not involved in that part.